# Xcode not detecting my device

Tags: xcode, ipad, device

I upgraded my iPad device OS version recently to 5.1.1 (9B206). From that my Xcode is not detecting my device. Am just getting iOS Device and simulator options in my Xcode. But am getting my device  in older version of Xcode and iTunes. For this i updated my MAC OS version to 10.7.4 and Xcode version to 4.3.3. But still am facing the same problem. Now how to make my Xcode to detect my device?

Comment: I just had the same problem after updating my iPad 2 to iOS 6.1.3. The problem turned out to be that my version of xcode wasn't the most recent version, so it didn't have the SDK I needed to develop for 6.1.3.

Comment: Had this issue with Xcode 9.4.1 and an iPhone 7 with iOS 11.4. After trying everything in the answers here I restarted the iPhone and that worked.

Comment: Today it took me a while to understand why my newly installed Xcode did not recognise my iPad. I just needed to read the logs though. "This iPad runs 14.2. To run on this device, please update to a version of Xcode that supports iOS 14.2. " Turns out that I am using a beta iOS version on the iPad. Worth checking this.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Open the Organizer in Xcode, go to devices, find your device and click the option to use for development

Comment: You might also need to right click and then choose "Add to member center"

Comment: I can't find the devices option in the organizer.

Comment: Is the screen under "Window -> Devices and Simulators" the same thing this was referring to? I don't see my iPad in there either anyway

Answer (score 153):

This Worked for me.

- Quit Xcode.
- Disconnect the device.
- In a terminal window, type: `sudo pkill usbmuxd` (it will be restarted
  again   automatically)
- Restart Xcode
- Connect the device

Your device should now be visible again in Xcode!

Comment: additionally plugged into another USB port worked for me

Comment: It's been 6 years and this is still the answer.

Comment: Welcome to 2023. "The bug fix just works", unlike Apple products.

Comment: Don't forget to turn off VPN!

Answer (score 18):

I just plugged into another USB port and it detected by device.

Answer (score 7):

In another case, check the "iOS Deployment Target" in "Build Settings",
if the target iOS version number is great than the version of device,
then the device will not show in the list.

Say that, the "iOS Deployment Target" == 7.0, and the version of device is 6.0,
to solve the problem by change the "iOS Deployment Target" to 6.0 or lower.

Answer (score 4):

If the chosen answer still does not work for you try this:

1. Select the project in project explorer
2. Select the target on the main window
3. Select Build Settings
4. Select Deployment
5. Select iOS Deployment Target. Change it to the version of your device. (e.g. iOS 5.1)

Answer (score 4):

I was also faced the same issue in Xcode, my device was not detected after update the Xcode latest version(7.3.1)

Done so many things what suggested in the web-search but still the device was not detected.

Finally, I just quit and open the Xcode my device was detected(oh my bad).

Answer (score 3):

This SO answer solved it for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/56054170/5813473 .

```
sudo killall -STOP -c usbd
```

did the magic.

Well later I had to unplug/plug in again at occasions, but that 'killall' really solved the original issue.

Comment: This also worked for me.  It's quicker than a reboot.

Comment: After resetting usbd, xcode announced the code was already running on my phone and asked me if I wanted to replace it. When I said yes, it then announced it had to fetch symbols and went away for a couple of minutes. It then ran my code.

So perhaps, had I checked my phone and had seen the code was running, killed it and then attempted to set it as Xcode's destination, that *might* have sufficed.

Answer (score 2):

Most recently, Xcode 8.3 and iOS 10.3 seems to have more security around Xcode accessing the iPad/iPhone. My sequence:

- Rebooted the machine,
- Attached the iPad,
- Gone through a "trust this computer" security cycle on both iMac and iPad
- Xcode can now see the device

Answer (score 2):

In my case, restarting Mac worked and no other solution.

Answer (score 2):

Recently (2022) I've noticed that the iPad prompt to "Trust this Computer" won't appear unless using an Apple USB-C cable. Apple reps assure me they aren't doing any funny business here, but I have tried every cable I can find, including several thunderbolt 3 and 4 cables and Anker cables. Worth trying an Apple cable if still having problems.

Answer (score 2):

I beat my head against this problem for hours before I realized that the problem was being caused by NordVPN.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes restarting Xcode helps. Give it a shot.

Answer (score 1):

I updated my iPad (it's in Settings -> General -> Software Update, near the top) and restarted my computer and Xcode sees it now.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW I tried all the tips in this thread and nothing would work: from reboots, command line statements, unplugging, different USBC ports, etc. I also tried something not mentioned here (yet) by going to "Settings > General > Reset > Reset Location & Privacy" ... however even this didn't work.

Later on in the evening I was in a different room of the house and out of nowhere I got the "Trust This Computer" prompt on my iPad. I of course tapped "Trust" or whatever and then magically my Mac laptop finally sees my iPad.

I realize I'm not really giving a helpful tip/fix here - just sharing how things went for me in case anyone finds useful.

iPad: iOS 13.4.1 | Macbook laptop: OSX 12.3.1

Answer (score 0):

Just simple, close the project on your XCode. Just right-click on the XCode in the taskbar and give a quit option.  After open the XCode from the directory, it will detect your device. It also work on Xcode version 11.2.1

1. close your project or XCode.
2. Give Right click on the Xcode in MAC tabbar and give the Quit option.
3. Reopen the project from your finder(project place).

The device will be automatically detected.

Answer (score 0):

In mac OS **Ventura** - try settings -> Privacy -> Allow accessories to connect.

Answer (score 0):

**What I tried?**

1. Tried clearing trusted computer.
2. Tried restarting mac.

**How it worked?**

1. I had my iphone connected to the mac via cable, disconnected it.
2. Disconnected the ipad and reconnected in different USB - C port in my mac and there I see the sneaky popup with Trust this computer.

Answer (score 0):

Restarting the iPhone/iPad did the trick, when connecting the cable, the "Trust this computer" alert appeared finally.

Answer (score -3):

Open the Windows in Xcode, go to devices. If Device is visible in Left side, Right click and select "Show in Destination Menu".

Enjoy..

Comment: What "Windows"? I see the "Window" menu item when I'm in Xcode.