# iPhone constantly disconnecting while working in Xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, debugging

I've been developing an app for a while and I haven't had any problems running the app on the device.. now a few days ago, whenever I connect the iPhone, it plays its little "ka-chink" sound and shows up in Xcode, but after a few seconds it disconnects and reconnects with another "la-chink" and keeps doing this until I want to throw it out of the window.

Of course, it's not possible to debug on the device with the constant disconnections, so I just:

- connect the device
- run the app on the device
- app crashes
- I remove the cable
- restart the app and it runs fine

I've tried various thing to get the phone to work properly again but to no avail so far.. anybody experienced this? any solutions?

Update: cable and connector fine, no hardware trouble.

Comment: Is the cable broken ? Try a different one.

Comment: is the port connector full of fluff/dust? this causes the same thing. Otherwise broken cabler as CW0007007 says.

Comment: It's definitely not a hardware fault. The same cable with the same device work fine on my Mac Pro 2009. Same Xcode version and same dev account (sync-ed).

Comment: @Frank R., you know, the cable has two ends.

Comment: Correct, everything has an end except a cable which has two.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the end removing expired certificates (current ones were already installed) solved the problem.

Comment: where did you remove these certificates?

Comment: how did you remove those certificates?

Answer (score 50):

I think this is not the problem with the device/Mac port/USB cable.

This seems to be an issue with `usbd` in Mac OS. The following can solve the issues:

Open Activity Monitor -> View -> All Processes -> Search for `usbd` -> Double click -> Quit -> Force Quit

**Using terminal:**

`sudo killall -STOP -c usbd` will pause the issue related process

If you want to resume the process for any reason use the following command

```
sudo killall -CONT usbd
```

This solution is working in MacOS Catalina as well.

Comment: I had this problem for years, always though it is bc of some problem with the cable or the mac itself, and the weird thing is sometimes I would touch the cable and it'd work :/ Once I found this, I felt stupid

Comment: @SeanGoudarzi you are not the only one, I went through every cable that I could find to fix this issue. You would think that Apple would have solved this by now.

Comment: 3 years later and at least as many OS major versions: still having to use this work-around.

Answer (score 9):

**If the problem appeared after Big Sur update, don't worry!** This issue has occurred in the past, after major macOS updates, or when users attempt to connect an iPhone for the first time to a new Mac computer. Fortunately, there is a permanent working fix that you can apply using a special command in the Terminal app.

1. Connect your device
2. Open terminal
3. Copy/paste the following command in the Terminal window:

   **sudo killall -STOP -c usbd**

Thats all! Hope it will help!

Answer (score 6):

The only thing that worked for me (tried many things) was to reset Location and Privacy settings on the iPhone:

Settings -> General -> Reset -> Reset Location & Privacy

As of iOS 15, this setting is in:

Settings -> General -> Transfer or Reset iPhone -> Reset -> Reset Location & Privacy

Comment: This is the only thing that magically worked for me. No apparent reason.

Comment: ```Settings -> General -> Transfer or Reset iPhone -> Reset -> Reset Location & Privacy```

Comment: Thanks Chris, added to the answer.

Comment: Does not works for me, even. I have reset all settings.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove and reactivate your phone from the devUsage in the organizer

Answer (score 0):

*Note: this may not be a permanent fix. Starting having the error again after 8 hours of no problems.*

I just had this problem (devices would connect, then randomly disconnect any time while using Xcode, or not even doing anything, sometimes they would reconnect but after a while I had to completely restart the computer). I fixed it by essentially **resetting the "trust this computer" for all of the devices registered to my Mac**. I am unsure how I may have gotten my computer to this state; I did change the "name" of my computer in Terminal and that may have done it.

Thanks to this site for pointing me in the right direction: http://andyaffleck.com/2014/11/07/fixing-trust-this-computer-problem/

In `/var/db/lockdown` there are plist files. I couldn't get access into the folder from the Finder, but using `sudo` in terminal let me list the files, and I could delete them with `sudo rm`, one at a time. Somehow the plist files were corrupt or incorrect.

Then after a restart, when I plugged in my phones again, the `trust?` dialog showed up on the phone, I accepted, and now I have not had a disconnection.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the port that connected to cable is worked for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30651500)

Answer (score 0):

it's work for me : sudo killall -STOP -c usbd